# Why can't I install libc6-dev

Tags: c, linux

I want to compile a c file, but an error occurs after entering the compile command.

```
~$ gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

```
fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I installed libc6-dev according to the method on the Internet

```
~$ sudo apt install libc6-dev
```

Then this error appeared

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11.3) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.23-0ubuntu11.3)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I followed the method

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  ubuntu-advantage-tools
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

```
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  ubuntu-advantage-tools
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11.3) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What should I do

Comment: Try to check the version of the gcc first: `gcc --version` and then reinstall/upgrade it: `sudo apt install --resintall gcc-{v}`

Comment: »» but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed «« : `2.31-0..9.2 is the Ubuntu 20.04 "focal-update" version → Something wrong with your `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Comment: @yemo Thank you for replying to my question, I tried your way, but there was an error  `E: Command line option --resintall is not understood in combination with the other options`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thank you for replying to my question, I'm a novice, if I understand correctly, is this what you mean? `No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal`

Comment: Your question has lines with "xenial" : That's Ubuntu 16.04 . Suggest : Comment out "xenial lines" if you have Ubuntu 20.04 : `cat /etc/issue` ......... About `libc6-i386` : 32bit may not be supported with 20.04 .

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thank you so much!! I changed the mirror source and installed libc6-dev, and it is ready to compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have debian, but I think [this](https://linux.debian.devel.narkive.com/hFb375V6/libc6-dev-have-unmet-dependencies-in-stable-bullseye) solution can help you. This is the new line I added to my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try installing a specific version of libc6

```
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt upgrade
    
 sudo apt install libc6=2.35-0ubuntu3
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: this worked without any non-free stuff. thank you. don't know how I got myself into this mess, but I'm happy you helped me get out of it :)